# Xamarin iOS crashes in NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CustomView", this, null)

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have created new CustomView.xib file and associated to code-behind class. But when i try to initialise the view, the app getting crashed as below mentioned error.

**MonoTouch: Could not install sigaction override, unexpected sigaction implementation.**

NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("CustomView", this, null); // App crashes here.

CS class file:

```
public partial class CustomView : UIView
{
    public CustomView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {

    }

    public override void AwakeFromNib()
    {
        base.AwakeFromNib();
    }
}
```

Designer class:

```
[Register("CustomView")]
partial class CustomView
{
    [Outlet]
    UIKit.UIView contentView { get; set; }

    void ReleaseDesignerOutlets ()
    {
        if (contentView != null) {
            contentView.Dispose ();
            contentView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

1. Build Action is set to interfaceDefinition.
2. File owner of the xib is set the class name "CustomView"
3. AwakeFromNib override method also implemented.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited:**

We came across with similar kind of issue after a long time but with different exceptions says "Object Null Reference" on "contentView" in the AwakeFromNib method. App crashes when you try to access the ContentView inside the AwakeFromNib method. This happened only on iOS 9.3.x. The following fix might help someone if they face the same kind of issue.

```
[Export("initWithFrame:")]
public SampleHeaderView(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
{
    Initialize();
}

[Export("initWithCoder:")]
public SampleHeaderView(NSCoder coder) : base(coder)
{
    Initialize();
}

public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib();
}

private void Initialize()
{
    if (this.ContentView != null)
    {
        this.ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where using `CustomView`.You can show complete `CustomView.cs` and where using it.

Comment: Could you please create sample and share it?
Normally I create static method with code like below:
`Nib = UINib.FromName("GroupFooter", NSBundle.MainBundle);`
`var view =(GroupFooter)Nib.Instantiate(null, null).First()`

Comment: Hi, have you solved this? If other problem, I will update my answer.

Comment: It is not resolved, seems to be an issue with Visual Studio for Mac, it is happening only when we create XIB in an existing project. Alternatively, we created an empty project and implemented functionalities related to XIB and moved to our existing project. Note: We could not able to edit the XIB in our existing project, it is creating some other issue, so we did everything with Xcode. I think the problem is with sync between VS and Xcode.